# Executing .NET Core console application on Linux: runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App not found

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I have experience with .NET on Windows, now I try to start with .NET Core on Linux. I will mostly be interested in developing and building applications on Windows, but for Linux.

I installed:

- [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 19 on VM
- .NET Core 2.1. (`dotnet --version` shows 2.1.500).
- Visual Studio Code and C# extensions.

**On Windows:**

I created a standard *Hello, World!* application from a template in .NET Core 2.1. It builds, compiles and runs without problems.

I copied solution files to Linux and with Visual Studio Code build and run it. No pb. Perfect.

On Windows, I published a self-contained package for linuxmint.18.3-x64 RID (~80 MB for "Hello, World!", but who cares), copied it to Linux and executed. No pb. Perfect.

Then I published a framework-dependent package (5 MB), copied it, but when I try to run it, it shows an error message:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (MyApp.deps,json) was not found:
>
> package: 'runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version:'2.1.6'
>
> path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcoreapp2.1/Microsoft.CSharp.dll'

What is the reason? It looks like .NET Core was installed correctly, is there anything more to install?

Comment: Can't you just install the missing package through nuget: `dotnet add package runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App --version 2.1.6`?

Comment: I believe .net core doesn't yet fully support self-contained applications

Comment: The framework-dependent version shouldn't depend on the linux-x64 package. how exactly did you publish? what does your csproj file contain?

Comment: @MitkoRusev that's one of .NET Core's main features.
@javadamiry no, don't suggest that, it's a RID-split of the `M.NETCore.App` packages via `runtimes.json` fallbacks.

Comment: @Martin Ullrich csproj contains:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
   <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;linuxmint.18.3-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

I right click a project, select Publish then select RID and "framework dependent".

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same problem wit version 2.2.2

Comment: Nope. Still the same pb. :-(